# Trigger ReCaptcha v3 strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to implement ReCaptcha V3 in my website. But I've been pulling the few hairs that I had left out, as Google doesn't seem to care about docs at all...

And all examples I see are all the simple examples, not really what you would use in prod.
My challenges:

1. The 1st time I press Submit, the token isn't passed to my PHP for some reason, why not?
2. The 2nd and further times I always get the same "challenge_ts" back, why? The token is different each time...
3. Lastly, just wanted to check if my assumption is correct that after a success/fail with score you don't execute JavaScript (as that can be modified), but only PHP code?

Here's my index.html code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=xxx"></script>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".fixed-top">
     <!-- contact form demo container -->
    <div style="max-width: 768px; margin: auto;">

        <!-- contact form -->
        <div class="card">
            <h2 class="card-header">Contact Form</h2>
            <div class="card-body">

                <form id="myform" class="contact_form" method="post" action="mail.php">

                    <!-- form fields -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>

                        <!-- form message prompt -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="contact_msg" style="display: none">
                                    <p>Your message was sent.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" class="btn btn-success" name="post">
                        </div>

                        <!-- hidden reCaptcha token input -->
                        <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- References for the opitional jQuery function to enhance end-user prompts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#myform').submit(function() {

        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('xxx', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
            // console.log(token);
            document.getElementById("token").value = token;
            console.log(token);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<script src="form.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's my form.js code:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var message = $('.contact_msg');

    $('.contact_form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // FIRST TIME NOT GRABBING DATA
        var token = $('#token').val();
        console.log(token);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'form.php',
            data: { token:token} 
        })
        .done(done_func)
        .fail(fail_func);
    });

    // Success function
    function done_func(response) {
        message.fadeIn()
        message.html(response);
        setTimeout(function () {
            message.fadeOut();
        }, 50000);
        // form.find('input:not([type="submit"]), textarea').val('');
    }

    // fail function
    function fail_func(data) {
        message.fadeIn()
        message.html(data.responseText);
        setTimeout(function () {
            message.fadeOut();
        }, 20000);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

And here's my form.php code:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // print_r("code:".$_POST['token']);

    # BEGIN Setting reCaptcha v3 validation data
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
    $data = [
        'secret' => "xxx",
        'response' => $_POST['token'],
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    ];

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );

    # Creates and returns stream context with options supplied in options preset 
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    # file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    # Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable
    $res = json_decode($response, true);
    # END setting reCaptcha v3 validation data

    print_r($response);

    # Post form OR output alert and bypass post if false. NOTE: score conditional is optional, since the successful score default is set at >= 0.5 by Google. Some developers want to be able to control score result conditions, so I included that in this example.
    if ($res['success'] == true && $res['score'] >= 0.5) {

        // ONLY EXECUTE PHP CODE? NOT LET JAVASCRIPT DECIDE NEXT STEPS?
        http_response_code(200);
        echo '<p class="alert alert-success">Success!</p>';

    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                Error! The security token has expired or you are a bot.
             </div>';
    }}
```

Test site:
https://www.citydiscovery.com.au/login/index.html

P.s. what does "action" do in the execute function of grecaptcha? Does it have any purpose?

Comment: Why are you calling `grecaptcha.ready` only within the submit event handler of the form? That is probably the reason already for your issue with it not sending a token on the first submit.

Comment: @CBroe fair point, sorry...but I still feel a bit more coding examples would have been nice if I see how many people struggle with it.

Comment: @CBroe just copied it also above the submit function.
It did now work the first time, however issue number 2 is still present. Each time the response is the same, including challenge timestamp. Any idea why?

Comment: I’d guess the challenge timestamp corresponds to the time when you called `grecaptcha.execute`. If you are only doing that once, but send multiple requests using AJAX afterwards - then I’d think that is probably normal.

Comment: Hmm not feeling that's that the case.
Each time I submit the form, the #myform submit is called, which calls grecaptcha.execute and gets a new token.

I can see the token is different each time so it must have correctly used the execute function, yet the timestamp stays the same. I added my website example to this post, just for people to test. Seems incorrect, doesn't it?

Comment: The token it sends appears to be different every time, and I get a success response each time. Not sure what actual _problem_ would need solving here now?

Comment: If everything works, that would be great and yes, then thanks for your help. The "issue" to me seemed that the timestamp is the same each time...which I think is strange if I submit it again 10 seconds later, returning me the old timestamp. That's the only question remaining...

In other examples that behaviour doesn't seem to happen...

Comment: As I said, calling `grecaptcha.execute` only in your form submit handler, appears to make rather little sense to me. That is not what the example in the docs is suggesting either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure what the issue was, but I'm now able to get a new timestamp each time by using a different code example from a YouTube video.

It's very tricky though, and so far have not seen any proper implementation at all.

Still coding, but some advice:

- It takes around a second for the execute function to fetch a new token, so I built in a 1 sec delay before the button is enabled again
- As mentioned in a comment, use the example ready function, but also call the function when submitting a form
- Tokens are supposedly only valid for 2 mins, so there could still be an issue by calling the ready function on page load after 2 mins. Not yet sure how to solve that as calling the function when submitting the form doesn't work the first time

Comment: how I understand it is that the token is created not by the ready method but rather the execute method.